# c++ operator overload

Tags: c++

```
//#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T, class X> class Obj{
T my_t;
X my_x;
public:
    Obj(T t, X x):my_t(t),my_x(x){}
     operator T() const {return my_t;}
};
int main()
{
    int iT;
    Obj<int, float> O(15,10.375);

    iT = O;
    cout << iT << endl;
    return O;
}
```

about this line : `operator T() const {return my_t;}`
is this operator overload? but I am not so understand which operator is been overloaded?
anybody can explain it for me? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is operator overloading. The operator that has been overloaded is the casting operator to type `T`. That's the operator that is invoked when you ask the compiler to convert an `Obj<T,X>` into a `T`.

Comment: the `const` means the same as with any other function, its a signal to the compiler that no member data of the object should be modified in the function call.  That is true since a copy of `my_t` is returned.